# 2018-03-31T05:37:57.000Z to universal timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have universal time `2018-03-31T05:37:57.000Z` and have to change this to timestamp `1520919620673` how can i change this please help

Comment: [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: You can use something like this `new Date('2018-03-31T05:37:57.000Z').getTime()`, but the output timestamp is bit different from your desired timestamp.

Comment: Could you explain why you believe that the UTC time you specified should match the timestamp you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var utcTime = "2018-03-31T05:37:57.000Z";
//create Date object and using getDate() function
var date = new Date(utcTime);
var unixTimestamp = date.getTime();
console.log(unixTimestamp);
```

Please refer to js [online document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for further details.

By the way, the UTC time and the universal timestamp your provided do not match. Please check some [online converter](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) as reference.

Comment: Thank you it Works

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should understand first how date function working.

Javascript date getTime() method returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time. The value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00.

You can use this method to help assign a date and time to another Date object.

```
 var d = new Date( "May 25, 1992 21:15:20" );
     console.log(d.getTime() );
```

same in your case, you just have to take it in another variable and use .getTime()

```
let dateObj = new Date("2018-03-31T05:37:57.000Z");
console.log(dateObj.getTime());
```